# How to process a single attribute in a SQL request twice times?

Tags: shortcode, sql, customization

I have created a shortcode with only ONE attribute, but the SQL request needs TWO attributes for `%s`, because of the subquery. The following SQL does not work, because the second `%s` does not have a value.

When I create a workaround with a second attribute, the second `%s` in SQL subquery works as expected, but I don't want to use two identical attributes.

How can I duplicate the single attribute for using it twice in SQL request?

```
 <?php
 // Shortcode: [my_shortcode market="USA"]
 function showSomething( $country ){
    $country = shortcode_atts( array(
        'market' => '',
        ), $country);  

     global $wpdb;

     $sql = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( 
        "SELECT `Date`, `Field1`, `Field2`, `Field3`
         FROM   `table` 
         WHERE  `country` = %s
         AND    `Date` = (SELECT DISTINCT `Date`
                          FROM `table` 
                          WHERE `country` = %s
                          ORDER BY `Date` DESC
                          LIMIT 1)", $country ) );

   ....
   return ....
 }
 add_shortcode('my_shortcode', 'showSomething');
```

Comment: You could use `%1$s` instead, to use the same attribute several times.

Comment: Replacing both `%s` with `%1$s` results in an empty SQL result, but it should provide one row (cross-validated manually with phpMyAdmin).

Comment: `LIMIT 1)", $sql ) );` --- $sql isn't defined.

Comment: Oh, yes, you are right. I've replaced `$sql` with `$country` but `%1$s` in query and subquery is not providing database result. Maybe it is not possible to use `%1$s` twice times in one request?

Comment: As far as I understand, wordpress 4.8.2 specifically restricts the  convenient usage of numbered placeholders like %1$s, %1$d, %1%f  in WPDB::prepare. (https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/41925)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress 4.8.2 specifically restricts the convenient usage of numbered placeholders like `%1$s`, `%1$d`, `%1%f` in `WPDB::prepare`. ([core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/41925](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/41925)).

To avoid usage of numbered placeholders, SQL query has to be rearranged to just use only one `%s`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.`Date`, y.*
FROM `table` t
LEFT JOIN  `table` y ON (t.`Date` = y.`Date`) 
WHERE t.`country` = %s
ORDER BY t.`Date` DESC
LIMIT 1
```